# "can't access dead object" error selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, selenium-server

So before someone suggests there are already plans to migrate this IDE project to Webdriver, but this will not happen for a while. So for the time being I am forced to maintain these IDE scripts.

We are rolling out a new UI on our page and I was fixing the tests to work with the new model. The model is in an iframe here is my code

```
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>id=iframeAuthorizeNet</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=txtCardNum999</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

... Do some work in the model

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=btnSavePaymentItem999</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>relative=top</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=PageContent_page_payment_lnk</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>link=Delete</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=button.btn.btn-red</td>
    <td>Update</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.card-display.row &gt; a</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>2500</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=button.btn.btn-red</td>
    <td>Add</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=PageContent_page_headTitle_lbl2</td>
    <td>Update Payment Information</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=PageContent_page_transactions_lnk</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=PageContent_page_recentChargesTitle_lbl</td>
    <td>Charges</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>openAndWait</td>
    <td>${BaseURL}/aboutus.aspx</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

So the issue is with the openAndWait this call is always giving me a `Can't access dead object" error. I tried changing this to a click on the element that would take me to the new page and this also triggered the error. All calls after these work fine and I can even see when I watch the test that the click command worked and the page navigated but it was still reported as "Can't access dead object" so my test still appears to have failed.

Some other useful information I am only encountering this issue when ran on the standalone server (2.53.1). When I run the tests through the Firefox plugin everything works fine.

Has anyone else ran into this? Seems to me to be related to the page change.

Comment: Where is that Base URL set/What is the Base URL?

Comment: in an earlier test case I call "housekeeping", it is set to one of our internal dev environments. Did this so it could be configurable.